# How long does the ball take to reach half of its terminal velocity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

A ball of mass m = 0.1kg falls from rest under the influence of gravity (on
earth) in a medium that provides resistance that is proportional to its velocity. For a velocity of
0.2 m/s, the resistance force on the object is measured to be 1N.

How long does the ball take to reach half of its terminal velocity?

I found the terminal velocity to be -.0196 m/s but I am not sure how to model the velocity equation to solve for time t when the velocity is half of my terminal velocity.  Thank you!

Comment: Well, the first step would be to draw the forces that are applied to the ball. Namely, gravity and the aerodynamic resistance (drag). Their sum is then equal to mass times acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

By Newton's second law (rate of change of momentum is equal to net force applied),

$$m \frac{dv}{dt} = mg - \alpha v$$; $\alpha $ is a constant, $\alpha v$ is the resisitive force.

Integrate w.r.t. time to get $v$ in terms of $t$.

$v|_{t = 0} = 0$ and  $v|_{t \to \infty} = v_t$, terminal velocity is attained when $\frac{dv}{dt} = 0$, i.e. $v_t = \frac{mg}{\alpha}$

$m \int_{0}^{\frac{v_t}{2}} \frac{dv}{mg - \alpha v} = \int_{0}^{t_0}dt\quad$; $t_0$ is the required time.

Comment: I get the the LHS the answer -.0139, which would mean my t is negative?

Comment: I took the downward direction as positive. If you take downward direction as negative, RHS of first equation changes to $\alpha v - mg$ and v_t is also negative then. Time should come out as positive. In my original equations use positive valued v_t and you will get positive time

Answer (score 0):

The net force acting on the ball is:$$F=(\text{Force due to Gravity/ Weight)}-(\text{Resistive Force})$$
Now weight is $ mg=0.1\times 9.8=0.98 N$ and resistive force is $F_r\propto v$ or $F_r=kv=5v$ (by given condition). So, the net force becomes:
$$F = 0.98-5v$$
By Newton's second law of motion, $F=ma=0.1\displaystyle\frac{dv}{dt}$. Hence
$$0.1\frac{dv}{dt}= 0.98-5v$$
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=9.8-50v$$
$$\frac{1}{9.8-50v}dv=dt$$
Integrating both sides,
$$-\frac1{50}\ln(9.8-50v)=t+c^*$$
$$9.8-50v = ce^{-50t}$$
$$v=\frac{9.8-ce^{-50t}}{50}$$
Since the ball starts at rest so $v(0)=0.$ Hence $$\frac{9.8-c}{50}=0\ \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ c=9.8$$
So $$v= \frac{9.8-9.8e^{-50t}}{50}$$
The terminal velocity is found by putting $t\rightarrow \infty$ i.e. $v_t=\displaystyle\frac{9.8}{50}=0.196$.

Now, we have to find the time $t$ for which $v(t)=\displaystyle\frac{v_t}2=0.098$. So
$$\frac{9.8-9.8e^{-50t}}{50} = 0.098$$
$$9.8-9.8e^{-50t} = 4.9$$
$$9.8e^{-50t} = 4.9$$
$$e^{-50t}=0.5$$
$$t = \frac{\ln0.5}{-50}=0.01386 \text{ seconds}$$